# illegal offset string in for each loop in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

How can I resolve this illegal offset string 'from' error in my laravel blade. I am sending data to it using this collection

```
  $results = [
            'name'          => $Fname,                  
            'from'          => $from,
            'to'            => $to,
            ];
```

and in blade:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
            <tr>
            <td>{{ $result['from'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $result['to'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ $result['name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why do you `foreach` over it?

Comment: @eden WebStudio - your outputting it as though it was an array of arrays. It is not. Don't do the for each loop, unless or if you do you can just '{{$result}}' without the for each loop you can do '{{$results['from']' etc...

Comment: You might be intending to create an array of arrays, if so, make sure $results has a [] after it so append to the $results array

Answer (score 0):

The $results need [] before the '='.

```
$results[] = [
'name'          => $Fname,                  
'from'          => $from,
 'to'           => $to,
];
```

Comment: Use foreach ($results as $key => $value) to get the correct offset and corresponding value.